# Extract underlined text from pdf

Tags: python, pandas, pdf, ocr

I am trying to extract data from a PDF which is in a table. I am able to extract the data using pandas and read the data.

Recently the data got changed and now I am suppose to extract only those values that are underlined in table that is in PDF. The table structure is same. But the data to extract has been underlined.bi tried OCR, tessaract to extract data but with no luck as they extracted all the data. But I only need underlined data.

If it helps the underline is in red color always.

I am using Python as programming language.

Comment: have you tried looking at tabular? It may help

Answer (score -1):

```py
for run in para.runs:
    if run.font.underline :
        underline.append(run.text)
```

Comment: email me er.sawant@gmail.com incase clear code is needed as i am unable to load with stackflow indents